# Not able to build Android NDK project fatal error: android/configuration.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated

Tags: android, build, android-ndk

I am building a complete native app in using Android NDK, when I try to build the app I am getting the following error:

```
D:/Softwares/android-ndk-r9c/sources/android/native_app_glue/android_native_app_glue.h:25:35: fatal error: android/configuration.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.
```

I am not getting why this error is coming. I have created an `Android.mk` file with following content

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := mynativeactivity
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := Log.cpp Main.cpp EventLoop.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS :=  -llog -landroid
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := android_native_app_glue
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
$(call import-module,android/native_app_glue)
```

Also, in the project properties I have added following Paths & Symbols

```
D:/Softwares/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include
D:/Softwares/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.8/include
D:/Softwares/android-ndk-r9c/sources/android/native_app_glue
```

Can anyone suggest what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I do not have Application.mk

Comment: Nothing is changed ....

Answer (score 0):

LOCAL_LDLIBS :=  -landroid is the problem.

The system is expecting the configuration.h file, as simple as that.

Why do you mean by project properties ? in eclipse ? .

ndk-build would not pick your ecplise project properties.

Please add Application.mk file and mention the APP_PLATFORM := android-9 ( not sure if it should solve the problem).Otherwise , add the include path LOCAL_C_INCLUDES in your android.mk file.